# porque as propriedades de css funcionam apenas em HTML e não no css externo

Tags: html5, css3

```
<button id="btn-info" type="button"></button>
```

Quando coloco o selector com as propriedades em css externo ele não funciona
mas se colocar diretamente no Style do html dá tudo certo.

```
#btn-info{
    display: block!important;
    background-image: url(icons/categorias/informatica/headset.svg);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%
}
```

Quando vou em source do menu do desenvolvedor  do navegador, vejo que meu trecho de css foi ignorado, mas se colo o mesmo trecho CSS ali funciona com hesito. 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como consigo modificar as propriedades pelo meu arquivo de CSS ?**

Comment: Coloque `!important` na frente, igual fez com `display` .. Digo isso porque não consigo ver o print, não tenho acesso a URL.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda o problema é  o navegador. obrigado, apenas reiniciei o pc e pronto OBG

Comment: Se funciona em `style` e não no CSS regra geral tem a ver com sobreposição de estilos, e resolve corrigindo a ordem de aplicação, alterando os seletores ou colocando `!important`. Como aparte não escreva texto em caixa alta, todos nós conseguimos ler bem.

Comment: cara é sempre bom quando vc fazer uma atualização muito pesada em seus códigos limpar os dados do navegador... dependendo é bom apagar a data toda do navegador pois pode esta em cache